# Regex and POST in same connection

Tags: regex, authentication, python-2.7, urllib2

please bear with me, i'm brand new to Python!

I'm trying to login to a website which uses PHP. The form contains two hidden fields, the value of one and the name of another are generated on page load.

My code below successfuly accesses the page and using regex manages to return the values - great!

The problem I am having is that I then generate my querystring that will be used for the POST (this contains the two values obtained earlier) and opens the url again. This generates brand new tokens/values and my originals are of no use.

Can someone shed some light on how I can connect to a site, use regex to get the values and then POST all in the same connection.

I hope i've made myself clear, if not please let me know.

Thanks in advance for your help.

```
import urllib2,urllib,re,cookielib

url='http://www.example.com/index.php'

req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.0.3 Gecko/2008092417 Firefox/3.0.3')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
link=response.read()
response.close()
token1=re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="return" value="(.+?)" />').findall(link)
token2=re.compile('<input type="hidden" name="(.+?)" value="1" />').findall(link)
print token1[0]
print token2[0]

username = 'username'
password = 'password'

cj = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cj))
login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password, 'return' : token1[0], token2[0] : '1', 'Submit' : 'Log in', 'option' : 'com_users', 'task' : 'user.login'})
opener.open('http://www.example.com/index.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/index.php')
```

FORM:

```
<form action="/index.php/welcome2" method="post" id="login-form" >
     <fieldset class="userdata">
          <p id="form-login-username">
               <label for="modlgn-username">User Name</label>
               <input id="modlgn-username" type="text" name="username" class="inputbox"  size="18" />
          </p>
          <p id="form-login-password">
               <label for="modlgn-passwd">Password</label>
               <input id="modlgn-passwd" type="password" name="password" class="inputbox" size="18"  />
          </p>
          <p id="form-login-remember">
               <label for="modlgn-remember">Remember Me</label>
               <input id="modlgn-remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes"/>
         </p>
         <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Log in" />
         <input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
         <input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.login" />
         <input type="hidden" name="return" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0xMjc=" />
         <input type="hidden" name="c813c34837e4e48e8e3268c0a42912a2" value="1" />
    </fieldset>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="/index.php/my-account/my-details?view=reset">
Forgot your password?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/index.php/my-account/my-details?view=remind">
Forgot your username?</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="/index.php/register">
Create an account</a>
</li>
</ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you write...

```
opener.open('http://www.example.com/index.php', login_data)
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/index.php')
```

Why not just this?

```
resp = opener.open('http://www.example.com/index.php', login_data)
```

I've never used this Python library, but my first reaction is that this would give you the response text all in one request, with which you can get the new token, wouldn't it?

**Update based on form:** It looks like your problem is you're POSTing the login info to `index.php` rather than `index.php/welcome`.

Comment: I was printing the resp variable (forgot to include the PRINT line in my code example) to see if the login had worked correctly. The php script loads the same page and a function deciphers the POSTed elements. The regex at the top has already opened the page and returned the old token values. How would i run the regex in your example? Thanks for your response

Comment: As far as I can guess you are using the correct tokens - the new tokens that the PHP script generates are for the *next* HTTP request. Maybe it would help if you posted the actual PHP page (or the HTML it generates if it's not public)?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, it should be working. I tried to manually POST the data in the address bar and the website returned "invalid  token" so something is definitely up. I'm trying to build an xbmc addon and don't really want to post all of the HTML. Will the form do?

Comment: yeah sure... and maybe an example of the token as well? I mean, one would think an "old" token should still work, even if a new one has been requested - there's no reason for it to expire - so there must be something else wrong there

Comment: I'm kinda new to Stack and when i post my form in the box it runs over the character limit. What's the best way for me to post the html of the form? Cheers

Comment: ah, the form "action" (i.e. the page you should be submitting to) is `/index.php/welcome`... so you should be posting to that URL rather than just 'index.php.'

Comment: Yeah, although my example is just index.php, i've tried POSTing to index.php/welcome2 as well with no success unfortunately. If the post were to be successful, the user.login changes to user.logout on the protected page. Cheers

Comment: I've noticed that returned HTML contains the text: Your session has expired. Please log in again.

Comment: could it be that you aren't submitting the "remember," "submit," "option," and "task" variables along with "username," "password," and the tokens? I would think at least the "task" (if not all) of those variables are required as well...

Comment: Would the following lines not submit those? login_data = urllib.urlencode({'username' : username, 'password' : password, 'return' : token1[0], token2[0] : '1', 'Submit' : 'Log in', 'option' : 'com_users', 'task' : 'user.login'})
opener.open('http://www.example.com/index.php', login_data)

Comment: ah I apparently didn't scroll over and see that... (other than "remember" but that's probably not an issue).

don't know what else the problem would be... are you sending that 'User-Agent' header *every* time you make a request, and not just the first time?

Comment: I'm sending it every time, is that wrong? How would I send it once if so? Cheers again for all your help

Comment: Ok, so it looks like when I login normally via a browser, a cookie is being set which contains the username as well as the cookie itself. Do you have any idea how to retrieve the cookie, modify it and then pass it back via POST using CookieJar?

Comment: i assumed you were already doing that because I saw the `CookieJar`, but looking at it again you probably aren't, which would be a problem - i'm not sure how you handle cookies in that library... the `response` object should have a way to get the cookies, and then you can store them in `cj`

Comment: So, I managed to get logged in by passing back the cookies. Only problem is, when I navigate to another page it logs me back out. I think this is something todo with the fact that urllib2 can't set keep-alive on the connection and it keeps closing. I've been looking at the requests python module but for the life of me I can't get XBMC to talk to it. I'll start another question for that tho. Cheers for all your help!